# Couldn't load this key (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key (new format))

Tags: ssh, putty

Пытаюсь добавить свои ключи из Linux к себе на машину, чтобы была возможность из винды по SSH заходить.

Так вот, скачал Putty и пытаюсь эти ключи добавить в pageant. На что мне выдается ошибки:

> Couldn't load this key (OpenSSH SSH-2 private key (new format))

Как я могу ее поправить?

Answer (score 1):

В общем, открыл ключ в PuttyGen и сохранил его там в формате ppk и все заработало.